# Выбрать все не NULL значения mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица, где поля с атрибутами, у некоторых есть значение, у некоторых нет  - NULL.

Можно как-то выбрать все не NULL значения у всех полей таблицы ?

Comment: where поле is not null

Answer (score 1):

Легко. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL`

Comment: через AND colN IS NOT NULL добавить поля по вкусу

Comment: Ну это для поля, а как-то для всех полей таблицы NOT NULL можно применить?

Comment: @VladShkuta Можно, надо написать такие проверки для всех полей. руками. Или возможно пересмотреть структуру БД что бы полей было не много

Comment: понял, то есть нельзя для всех полей сразу применить

Comment: @VladShkuta Ну никто не мешает на любом подходящем языке написать скрипт который посмотрит структуру таблицы и сгенерирует нужный запрос. А у вас в БД что ли есть записи где все поля NULL. Не понимаю, зачем может быть нужно проверять большое количество полей на NULL

Comment: У меня есть таблица типы недвижимости(дом,квартира,комерческая) И есть таблица атрибуты, там поля - площадь, этаж, высота потолка, к-во комнат, и т.д. Я как выбираю тип, к примеру квартира - и тогда вписываю нужные атрибуты(этаж,к-во комнат, и т.д.)